# Why The App Crashed After Processed a Command Using a setOnClickListener?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

So I am using firebase to upload my data by filling a form and sending a cover picture. After I filled the form and provide the picture, I pressed a "save" button, which is basically sending all those information and pictures to firebase and then return to the main activity. Before the main activity appears, the app crashed and this error appears:

```js
2022-08-16 20:49:53.847 21445-21445/com.example.gesit E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.gesit, PID: 21445
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.setEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.gesit.TambahProduk.saveProductInformation$lambda-6(TambahProduk.kt:313)
        at com.example.gesit.TambahProduk.$r8$lambda$WSqVgd-3d_M5F9vVqHMPnqwiv5o(Unknown Source:0)
        at com.example.gesit.TambahProduk$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.onComplete(Unknown Source:2)
        at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzi.run(com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks@@18.0.1:1)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8751)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
```

What caused this crash? Thanks.

Code for sending data and picture to firebase:

```js
    private fun saveProductInformation(downloadedUrl: String) {
        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
        val uid = auth.currentUser?.uid.toString()
        databaseReference =
            FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                .getReference("User")
        val productName = productName.text.toString()

        val productInfo =
            DataProduk(productName, uid)
        if (uid != null) {

            databaseReference.child(uid).setValue(productInformation)
                .addOnCompleteListener {
                    saveButton.isEnabled = false
                    Toast.makeText(this@AddProduct,"Product added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    hideProgressBar()
                }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Show us the code that produces that error.

Comment: Hi @AlexMamo , glad to see you again, code is provided. Thanks.

Comment: Where in your code are you using `.setEnabled()`?

Comment: @AlexMamo omg that solves the issue. It has nothing to do with Firebase, lol ur really amazing as always.